# How to create Allure history

Tags: java, selenium, appium, allure

I'm planning to run my Allure test scripts every day. After running Day 3 test scripts, how to see day1 & Day 2 test results along with Day3.
History is not loaded into history tab.

Answer (score 6):

What you need to do is just to copy (and replace) content of the history folder

- from: allure-report/history/
- to: allure-results/history/

You need to specify the location of the folders based on the structure of your project. 
In my current application, I made the small shell script as below:

```
mkdir build/allure-results/history
cp allure-report/history/* build/allure-results/history

allure generate --clean build/allure-results
allure open
```

After using these commands my report is properly generated and shows the history.

Comment: Can you show your report here please...I am trying to do above approach but it is not working...I am assuming I am doing something wrong but could not figure out it yet.

Comment: hi @SrinuKodi, what exactly would you like to see? The report you mean the HTML file? Or something more?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You can ignore my comment now. I have moved on to allure-server solution which took 30mins and it is providing all historical trends and more features. https://github.com/kochetkov-ma/allure-server

Answer (score 0):

I believe your Day 1, Day 2, Day 3, etc. results all need to be in the same folder you want to generate your report from.

Answer (score 0):

In a normal-ish setup, you would have two folders: allure-results and allure-report. Copy the entire contents of allure-report to allure-results (on prompt, select 'replace all existing files').
Now when you run the report, you should be able to see the history.